# Can I keep track of page version/variation for comments on Disqus?

Tags: comments, disqus, versioning

I have a site where I'd like to integrate user commenting.

Each page on the site has a version/variation of some sort -- think of an app version, an operating system the user has the app for, or the branding name and year model of a motor vehicle (or maybe even the country or language the user is from).

I am thinking that in the start, I'd like to keep all the comments together (perhaps apart from the language ones), regardless of which version of the page the user is looking at, to make sure the place doesn't just look completely deserted.

At the same time, I also worry that with the growth, all the mixed-version comments may become burdensome, as they'd be containing incorrectly classified or outdated information; and that'll be the perfect time to split them up to appear only on the pages of their respective versions, where such outdated information would still be very relevant to the outdated product being described (e.g., for archival purposes).

***Is there a way for Disqus to keep this extra information about which version/variation of the page the comment is being written or voted on, whilst still having the option to present all such comments at each variation of the page all together?***

Just to make it clear -- there will be about 10k pages (each must always have their own thread), each page will have about 3 to 4 major variations (like a brand-name vendor of an OEM product), and each major variation will independently have 10 to 30 minor ones (like monthly or early updates/releases).

So, from the example above, what I'd like to do is keep track of comments for every version, but originally show them all together in just 10k threads (but also have the ability to filter things down as needed).  Can Disqus do it?  Or what else could I use?